# Why bootstrap modal is not closing?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

Does anyone know what's wrong with below code? The modal is opened when I click the button that has to trigger this action, but when I click on close buttons that has `data-dismiss="modal"`, it happens nothing.

```
<div class="modal fade show" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-modal="true" style="display: block;">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title"> Schedule</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="/schedule" id="modal-form" method="post">
               <div class="input-container mb-3">
                  <textarea class="textarea-input" style="resize:none; width: 100%;" rows="5" maxlength="280" name="Text" required=""></textarea>
                  <br>
                  <div id="success-message" class="success-message mt-3" style="display: none;">
                     <span>Successfully scheduled</span>
                  </div>
                  <div id="error-message" class="error-message mt-3" style="display: none;">
                     <span>There was an error during scheduling</span>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Schedule</button>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="close btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might be a typo: `data-bs-dismiss` instead of `data-dismiss`

Comment: @disinfor, thank you so much. That was the problem.